# How to display text like (5% off) using data binding in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-databinding

I need to display text in text view (5% Off) using databinding. My code is

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:text="@{@string/percentage_off(priceUIModel.discountOfferPercentage)}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Heading2Lines.Size12.Light"
            android:textColor="@color/red_100"
            app:visibility="@{priceUIModel.discountOfferPercentage !=null}" />
```

In string.xml

```
<string name="percentage_off">%s\%% Off</string>
```

Simply need to add brackets front and back of the text. How can I modify this string.xml? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to add the brackets to your string?

Comment: Exactly. Like (5% Off).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.format()` command:

```
android:text='@{String.format("(%s)",@string/percentage_off(priceUIModel.discountOfferPercentage))}'
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks.